# Visual C++ compile error C2871 - <namespace> : a namespace with this name does not exist

Tags: com, interop

I am trying to create a ManagedWrapper dll that can be called from an MFC application that will not be compiled using /clr switch. In a header of my test MFC, I have declared the following:

```
#import "ManagedProxy.tlb"
using namespace ManagedProxy;
```

When I try to compile the test MFC application, I get error C2871: 'ManagedProxy' : a namespace with this name does not exist.  I am sure this has worked as recently as yesterday.  If I specify a wrong tlb file name, I get compile error C1083, which indicates to me that the tlb file is being loaded correctly.

Why is Visual Studio now complaining and why did it work before?

**Addition:**

I just found out that my proxy stopped working after I changed the namespace to ManagedProxy.  I have recompiled the Managed project, and the native application has as an Additional Include Path, the Debug folder of the managed project, so it should be referencing the latest tlb but it is not.  I tried an absolute path to the tlb, cleaned and rebuilt project with no luck.

Why is the tlb not the namespace change?

**Addition**
Used Object Browser to see what is in TLB and the namespace ManagedProxy is somehow renamed to something else.  I am also missing a couple of interfaces although they are marked with ComVisible(true).

Someone please help....

TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rename the namespace when you import.

```
#import "ManagedProxy.tlb" rename_namespace("ManagedProxy")
```

Comment: Thanks for that tip. Saved my day.  I also just found out that regasm completely ignores the namespace that contains classes and interfaces and instead uses the assembly name as namespace when assembly is registered for COM.  Also, if assembly name uses dot notation such as CompanyName.AssemblyName.Purpose you get error that assembly cannot be registered.  Visual Studio needs to be run as admin.  Just an FYI for others.

Comment: Anyone know why some of my interfaces marked with ComVisible(true) are not showing up when browsing managed object registered for COM?

Comment: Nice tip!  This also helped when I imported a managed C# assembly that has hierarchical namespaces.  The C++ compiler didn't like using namespace "Major.Minor" but renaming to MajorMinor worked!

Answer (score 0):

The interfaces not showing up are likely not marked public.

Comment: They are all marked as public.  They do not show up in Object Browser but fortunately can be consumed from C++.